# Magento 2 : How to add custom field in signup(CREATE ACCOUNT) page in frontend

Tags: magento2

How to add custom field in signup(CREATE ACCOUNT) page in frontend. I have tried some example module but i am getting this

**Error**
**"1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): Please upgrade your database: Run "bin/magento setup:upgrade" from the Magento root directory. 
The following modules are outdated:
Multi_Beta data: current version - none, required version - 0.1.1"**

```
InstallData.php

    <?php
    namespace Multi\Beta\Setup;
     use Magento\Framework\Module\Setup\Migration;
    use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
    use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
    use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
    class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
    {
        /**
         * Customer setup factory
         *
         * @var \Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory
         */
        private $customerSetupFactory;
        /**
         * Init
         *
         * @param \Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory
         */
        public function __construct(\Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory)
        {
            $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
        }
        /**
         * Installs DB schema for a module
         *
         * @param ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup
         * @param ModuleContextInterface $context
         * @return void
         */
        public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
        {

            $installer = $setup;
            $installer->startSetup();
            $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
            $entityTypeId = $customerSetup->getEntityTypeId(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY);
            $customerSetup->removeAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, "my_attribute");

            $customerSetup->addAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, "my_attribute",  array(
                "type"     => "varchar",
                "backend"  => "",
                "label"    => "My Attribute",
                "input"    => "text",
                "source"   => "",
                "visible"  => true,
                "required" => true,
                "default" => "",
                "frontend" => "",
                "unique"     => false,
                "note"       => ""

            ));
            $my_attribute   = $customerSetup->getAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, "my_attribute");

            $my_attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, ' my_attribute');
            $used_in_forms[]="adminhtml_customer";
            $used_in_forms[]="checkout_register";
            $used_in_forms[]="customer_account_create";
            $used_in_forms[]="customer_account_edit";
            $used_in_forms[]="adminhtml_checkout";
            $my_attribute->setData("used_in_forms", $used_in_forms)
                ->setData("is_used_for_customer_segment", true)
                ->setData("is_system", 0)
                ->setData("is_user_defined", 1)
                ->setData("is_visible", 1)
                ->setData("sort_order", 100);
            $my_attribute->save();
            $installer->endSetup();
        }
    }
```

customer_account_create.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
        <body>
            <referenceContainer name="form.additional.info">
                <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="my_form_additional_info_customer" template="Multi_Beta::additionalinfocustomer.phtml"/>
            </referenceContainer>
        </body>
    </page>
```

additionalinfocustomer.phtml

```
<fieldset class="fieldset create account" data-hasrequired="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('* Required Fields') ?>">
        <legend class="legend"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Additional Information') ?></span></legend><br></p>

<p>        <div class="field my_attribute required">
            <label for="my_attribute" class="label"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('My Attribute') ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <input type="text" name="my_attribute" id="my_attribute" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('My Attribute') ?>" class="input-text" data-validate="{required:true}" autocomplete="off">
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
```

module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Multi_Beta" setup_version="0.1.1">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Directory" />
            <module name="Magento_Config" />
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

When i run **magento setup:upgrade** in **CMD**
[image]

[image]

Comment: Check that setup_version in setup_module

Comment: Does this " php bin/magento setup:upgrade" run successfully after instaling this extension?

Comment: no.i have updated the question pls check again @DhirenVasoya

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do this steps.

1. Remove extension entry (Multi_Beta) from "`setup-module`" table.
2. Remove extension attribute entry(my_attribute) from "`eav_attribute`" table.
3. Run following command from CLI :

   php bin/magento cache:clean

   php bin/magento cache:flush

   php bin/magento indexer:reindex

   php bin/magento setup:upgrade

   php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

Comment: it didn't work, still  facing same problem. I want to create a checkbox  in frontend signup and save the value in table any other way to add checkbox without editing core files?

Comment: "Attribute with same code already exist" error occures when attribute already in your database, So confirm that you have already remove your attribute entry from database and then run above command.

Comment: Now error is gone, but i don't think that my phtml file is running. Am i missing something?  @Dhiren Vasoya

Comment: For above question, your error solve now, right?

Comment: Yes,  Thank you. Can you please suggest  any reference to create a new field in create user  registration  form?

Comment: you can create customer attibute programetically ans show while registration.